# Rails : SQLite3::SQLException with has_and_belongs_to_many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I get a new problem with my application.

I try to make a relationships many-to-many like this : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association
Here I use has_and_belongs_to_many to "connect" two tables : User & Pins

But I get this error when I try to count the number of pins of the user.

```
Showing /app/views/shared/_users_pins.html.erb where line #4 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: pins_users.user_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pins" INNER JOIN "pins_users" ON "pins"."id" = "pins_users"."pins_id" WHERE "pins_users"."user_id" = 102

line 4 :  <%= @user.pinss.count %>
```

(I need to use pinss instead of pins because otherwise rails search the class Pin instead of Pins, but it's so dirty :'( )

Here is my model :

```
class Pins < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :describe, :title, :url_img
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :team_id
 has_and_belongs_to_many :pinss
end
```

Thank ! =)

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use habtm, you need to create a join table manually , in your case
pinss_users with exactly two columns, the pins_id and the user_id.

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

as your error showed that user_id is missing in pins_users (no such column: pins_users.user_id)

ps: the double s in pinss is indeed strange, and I'm not sure if it adds to the problem in some way - shouldn't the join table be named pinss_users then? Are you sure pins it the correct name - what is a pins if not the plural of pin? If you absolutely must do this, you could add a custom pluralization for that.